# Equivalent of `python setup.py develop` in poetry

Tags: setuptools, python-poetry

With setuptools, I could use `python3 setup.py develop` and my development directory could be found by python3 without setting PYTHONPATH or running install. Any change in the current development directory is immediately available without running `python3 setup.py develop/install` again. This saves quite a lot of time during the development.

Is there a poetry equivalent?

**Update** There is a feature request https://github.com/python-poetry/poetry/issues/1214

Comment: Yes, `poetry install` :-)

Comment: I thought 'poetry install' installs the dependencies. So silly of me!

Comment: Both. `poetry install` installs the current project (as editable) and the dependencies (some as editable, if so specified).

Answer (score 15):

In poetry, the main project is installed as editable by default:

> *The current project is installed in editable mode by default.*

-- [Section "*Installing dependencies only*" of *Poetry*'s documentation](https://python-poetry.org/docs/basic-usage/#installing-dependencies-only)

It is also possible to install some dependencies as *editable* alongside the main project in the same virtual environment. For example:

```
[tool.poetry.dependencies]
Library = { path = "../Library/", develop = true }
```

Comment: I suspect that it _always_ installs it in virtualenv? Can I install for system python by doing 'python3 -m poetry install' or passing some other flag?

Comment: Yes, poetry always does everything in a virtual environment by default. I think I know what you are expecting now, but please ask another question and eventually link it here so that I can answer. Your original question is now answered, let's close this one.